# Way to pass a command to Matlab from tcsh?

Tags: shell-script, tcsh, matlab

I'm looking to call a Matlab script in my tcsh script and pass it a programmatically-generated function call (like `functionName(varName)`). Is there a way to call Matlab (or any other scripting language) and pass a command to it?

So far what isn't working is:

```
matlab && echo 'plotify($varName)' && echo 'exit'
```

That just starts Matlab and echos after I exit Matlab

Answer (score 0):

`matlab` has, I believe, a `-r` command line option that takes a *statement* to execute.

You should therefore be able to do

```
matlab -r "plotify($varName)"
```

This assumes that MatLab actually knows what `plotify()` is and that you are giving it reasonable data in the shell variable `$varName`.

Note: It was 20 years since I did anything useful in MatLab. Also, I'm not a `tcsh` user.

---

Your command,

```
matlab && echo 'plotify($varName)' && echo 'exit'
```

would start `matlab`, wait for it to terminate, and if it terminated without an error, it would execute the two `echo` statements.